# What exactly happens in Linux internally when an ethernet cable is connected?

Tags: linux, networking, network-interface

I would like to understand what exactly happens when a cable is being connected to the Ethernet port (assuming dynamic IP addressing):

1. What services are being run and how are they triggered?
2. What API calls need to be made to establish connection?

Extra question: How exactly is this possible to detect the signal when a cable is connected (I understand this question might not exactly be suited for this SE site)?

Answer (score 0):

I can only really answer the "extra question". "How to detect the signal when a cable is connected". So, assuming 10*/Base-T, there is a kind of a carrier signal that the device detects and makes that information available to the device driver. The device driver will typically send a message via the kernel logger that "ETHX: LINK DETECTED". That information also becomes available (in relatively recent versions of Linux) in the /sys hierarchy. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/808599/3849157 .

I believe udev rules can be configured to tirgger an action when a device's state has been changed. But I know not for sure if that's the case here.

If the dhclient / pump process is running and if it does its thing, that process will request a DHCP address, and if it obtains one from the DHCP server, will typically call one or more helper scripts that actually configure the OS networking. But it depends on the particular program that does this.

Answer (score 0):

The Kernel has a driver for whatever bus the port is on (PCI, USB, PCMCIA -- actually that one's more complex and nobody uses it anymore, so forget PCMCIA). That driver has mapped the registers on that bus (this is different from a CPU register) to memory and keeps a watch on them.

When a cable is plugged in, ethernet hardware changes its registers and the bus notices. The bus messages udev, which maps the bus ID to the appropriate driver (this can also happen in-kernel; depends on how it's set up). Udev may also wake up a userland process like pump or NetworkManager, probably through dbus, though this is getting way into "depends on how it's set up" territory.

Generally, udev has already set up the mapping for things like the port's symbolic name "eth1" or whatever, as well as what driver it uses, and it makes this information available to the rest of userland (and in some cases the kernel). It sits around listening to the bus software in the kernel for changes to devices on the bus -- this is pretty much exactly like how a USB stick gets automounted: bus talks to udev, udev talks to userland.

**TL;DR:** The hardware on the ethernet port communicates with the bus (PCI or USB or what have you), which then communicates with udev, which communicates with the rest of userland.